# Configure Remote Access on Windows 2012 Server without IIS

Tags: apache, iis, server, windows-server-2012

I am running through the procedure to create a Windows 2012 Server, and I need Remote Access enabled. However, when I run through the installation process, it tells me I need to install IIS. Well I don't want IIS because I will have an Apache server running, but I have no choice. In Windows Server 2008 there was no need to install IIS when configuring Remote Access ( which used to be a part of Network Policy and Access Services ).

What can I do if I need Remote Access, need Apache, and don't want IIS?

Comment: Probably this question should be posted on ServerFault forum. On side note IIS has nothing to do with remote access of machine.

Comment: Except that I am forced to install it

Comment: Probably you are trying to configure "Remote Server Administration" and not remote access to machine.

Comment: I choose Remote Access from the Add Roles and Features and it forces IIS installation. If you see this guide, the person already has IIS installed, but it forces me to install it. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/routing-and-remote-access-in-windows-server-2012-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I simply deleted the default website created with IIS, restarted Apache and it works fine.